# how to distribute(in order)a list to different length lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list with 12 elements, but i wnat to put them into 3 different length lists

list1 has 4 elements,  list2 has 3 elements,  list3 has 5 elements

but i want to put them in order(list1 -> list2 -> list3 -> list1 ..), ex:

`original_list[0] puts in list1[0]`

`original_list[1] puts in list2[0]`

`original_list[2] puts in list3[0]`

`original_list[3] puts in list1[1]`

`original_list[4] puts in list2[1]`

`original_list[5] puts in list3[1]`

how can I do that with program? or any algorithm?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think as per your requirement, I've constructed a program :

```
original_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
list1,list2,list3=[],[],[]

for i in range(0,12,3):
    if len(list1)<4:
        list1.append(original_list[i])
    if len(list2)<3:
        list2.append(original_list[i+1])
    else:
        list3.append(original_list[i+1])
    list3.append(original_list[i+2])
print(list1,list2,list3)
```

Comment: Thank you very very much, that's exactly what i want to do  :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies above~~ All of your replies are very helpful.
Last weekend, I found a more general way to do that.
`

```
ori_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
list1,list2,list3=[],[],[]

list1_num=8
list2_num=10
list3_num=2
max_num=max(list1_num,list2_num,list3_num)

ori_list_index=0
for i in range(0,max_num,1):
    print(i)
    if i<list1_num:
        list1.append(ori_list[ori_list_index])
        ori_list_index=ori_list_index+1
    if i<list2_num:
        list2.append(ori_list[ori_list_index])
        ori_list_index=ori_list_index+1
    if i<list3_num:
        list3.append(ori_list[ori_list_index])
        ori_list_index=ori_list_index+1
print(list1,list2,list3)
```

`